# Why Lead afterUpdate trigger fires immediately after afterInsert trigger?

Tags: trigger, leads

I created a brand new dev org and created a simple Lead trigger that fires on ***afterInsert*** and ***afterUpdate*** events.

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after insert, after update) {
    
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            System.debug('Lead trigger after insert');
        } else if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            System.debug('Lead trigger after update');
        }
    }
}
```

When I am creating a new Lead record ***afterUpdate*** trigger fires immediately after ***afterInsert*** trigger.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are no validation rules or custom formula fields on the object. It's a newly created org.

I want to send an email to the user when the trigger fires. So after lead creation, the user gets TWO emails. But that is not a big problem, it's just interesting, what caused the update.

What can cause this trigger, and how can I change it?

Comment: What's the problem with it firing...

Comment: @Girbot I want to send an email to the user when the trigger fires.  So after lead creation, the user gets TWO emails. But that is not a big problem, it's just interesting, what caused the update.

Comment: That would be good information to add to your question, plus the relevant code.

Comment: @Girbot Yes, thanks, but there are no resons for adding code for email sending.

Comment: Do you have any Flows, Process Builders, Workflow Rules, or any additional triggers? How about any installed packages that may be updating the lead on insert? There's a lot of things you need to check.

Comment: @sfdcfox No, it's a newly created org, I just deployed this trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same when I tested out some race conditions for Lead triggers/assignment rules/record triggered flow in a brand new empty scratch org.

What I can tell from my debugging is that when you manually create a Lead record in LEX, it lands you on to newly created Lead detail page. Salesforce triggers an update event for this Lead once again to update `IsUnreadByOwner` field on the record. I suppose this is a result of you, as the owner, viewing the record. I'm absolutely sure that the second update doesn't get contained in the original insert transaction and goes through a separate transaction (2 debug logs produced for both)

Field Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm)